# Match the routeParam with the ID property and display the relevant object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":"112",
    "title":"Title here",
    "date":"1234567890"
  }
  {
    "id":"113",
    "title":"Title here",
    "date":"1234567890"
  }
...
]
```

I have two partials/views. A list view which lists all of the objects, and a detail page which is triggered by an "ng-click" which takes as a parameter the "id" property.

I have my routes working, and a detail partial.

I built a service to performe the request, and two controllers:

```
var chatServices = angular.module('itemServices', ['ngResource']);

chatServices.factory('Item',['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('data.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
    });
  }
]);

  chatListApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'Item', "$location",
    function ($scope, Item, $location) {
      $scope.items = Item.query();
      $scope.detailPage = function (hash) { 
        $location.path(hash);
      }
    }]);

    chatListApp.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Item',
      function($scope, $routeParams, Item) {
        $scope.data = Item.query();
        $scope.itemID = $routeParams.itemID;
        }
    ]);
```

So, I have a url like http://domain.foo/112, and I want it to show the first object of my JSON file (or the data array, if you prefer). 
When I try {{data[0]}} in my view, I get the object, so how do I go about adding some logic and fetching the object with ID value equal to $scope.itemID (as in the routeParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the id, and you have the data, so you can loop over the data the get the item:

```
chatListApp.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Item',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Item) {
    $scope.itemID = $routeParams.itemID;
    $scope.data = Item.query(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.data[i].id === $scope.itemID) {
          $scope.item = $scope.data[i];
          break;
        }
      } 
    });
  }
]);
```

then use `item` in your view.

Update: Use `angular.forEach` to replace for loop like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item) {
  if (item.id === $scope.itemID) {
    $scope.item = item;
  }
});
```

Comment: Should I use "return" instead of break? is data.length safe to use? (browser support) and isn't there a shortcut for this, for example angularforEach?

Comment: `return` works as well. `data.length` should be safe here because your data is an array, isn't it? You can use `angular.forEach`, but you're unable to break the `angular.forEach`.

Comment: could you write how the .forEach would be syntax-wise? I was looking into it but can't make it work.

Comment: there's a syntax error in the forEach I think. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos You're right, I have missed the closing parenthesis. Fixed!

Comment: I still don't get any results in the detail page.

Comment: doesn't work either with the forEach or with the for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61077/discussion-between-george-katsanos-and-ye-liu).